# Должен не и Не должен - разница

Tags: частица

Всё-таки фельдшер фронтовик опытный и не должен упустить подростка, если бы тот захотел бежать (Василь Быков).

А дочь ты не должен осуждать, ― сказал С-ов, ― я её не осуждаю, и ты не должен (Даниил Гранин).

Человек не должен забивать себе голову всякой ерундой (Андрей Геласимов).

Кажется, я начинал понимать секрет: надо работать без утайки, я не должен бояться бумаги ― это самый близкий мой друг (Василий Аксенов).

*Не должен* означает по-моему, *не обязан*, то есть может делать что-то, а может и не делать (не запрещено).

Например: Он не должен гулять поздно по улицам. Означает, он может гулять, а может и не гулять, то есть ему не запрещается гулять.

Он должен не гулять поздно по улицам. Означает, что он обязан не гулять, то есть ему запрещается гулять.

*Не должен упустить подростка* - разве автор имел ввиду, что *не запрещается упустить подростка*? Как раз таки автор, наверное, имел ввиду, что *должен не упустить подростка*?

*Дочь ты не должен осуждать* означает, по-моему: *можешь осуждать, а можешь не осуждать.*

То есть автор должен был написать: Дочь ты должен не осуждать?

*Я не должен бояться бумаги* означает, строго говоря, логически рассуждая: *могу бояться, а могу и не бояться, то есть мне не запрещено бояться бумаги.*

*Я должен не бояться бумаги* - означает *Я обязан не бояться бумаги, мне запрещено бояться бумаги.*

*Человек не должен забивать себе голову всякой ерундой.* Здесь автор имел в виду: Человек должен не забивать себе голову всякой ерундой? Или все-таки он хотел сказать, что человек может забивать а может и не забивать себе голову всякой ерундой?

В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы:
Я не мог, не должен был забывать такие вещи.

Шаламов имел в виду, что он должен был не забывать такие вещи?

или то, что он не обязан был забывать такие вещи?

Answer (score 3):

Не должен = не обязан, это так, но есть и ещё значение обязательности или предположения, возможности, вероятности чего-л. (с неопр. ф. глаг.) Например: Да не должен бы сбежать = возможно, не сбежит, предположительно не сбежит. Мне кажется, что первый пример как раз в этом значении: не должен упустить подростка = предположительно не упустит, потому что опытный.

Он должен, долженствует = ему должно, надо, приходится, полагается, потребно, необходимо, следует. Это по словарю синонимов. Ты не должен осуждать = тебе не полагается осуждать.

Должен - краткое прилагательное от должный (такой, как нужно (надо), подобающий)

Не должен забивать себе голову всякой ерундой = не следует забивать голову, не надо забивать голову.

Я не должен бояться бумаги = мне не надо бояться бумаги.

Я не мог, не должен был забывать такие вещи = мне не следует забывать (от долженствовать).

Answer (score 2):

А мне вопрос показался интересным.

Если посмотреть в словарь, то у слова "должен" одно основное значение:ДОЛЖЕН, 1. с инф. **Обязан** (делать что-л., обладать каким-л. качеством). Таким образом речь идет **о долге, об обязанности,** например: ты должен помнить.

Если мы используем форму "не должен", то это **разрешение на свободу, освобождение от долга,** например: ты не должен ни перед кем отчитываться.

А теперь сравним такие варианты: ты должен помнить (1) - ты должен не забывать (2) - ты не должен забывать (3).  Вроде бы все три значения тождественны по смыслу, но почему форма "не должен" опять из свободы превратилась в обязанность. **Создается впечатление, что частица НЕ в выражении (3) просто механически переставлена**.

И тогда при дословном чтении получается несоответствии формы и смысла: Он не должен гулять поздно по улицам (у него нет обязанности гулять поздно по улице). Но мы же совсем не это имели в виду, а нечто совсем другое.

Answer (score 2):

Интересное наблюдение.
Действительно, значение "не должен" отличается от прямого отрицания долженствования. Фактически это именно "должен не", разве что в более мягкой форме высказанное.
Ничего подобного с другими словами выражающими модальность необходимости/свободы (может, обязан, вынужден и т. п.) не происходит. 
Почему это происходит, сказать трудно. У Людмилы объяснения этому тоже нет, хотя мысль о том, что "должен" - это именно прилагательное (в то время как остальные слова в этом ряду - переходные глаголы или причастия от них), имеет место...

Но все попытки списать тут на грамматику упираются в то, что подобное значение у "не должен" проявляется не всегда.

*Я не должен обращать внимания* - это-то уж никак нельзя заменить на *Я  должен не обращать внимания*. Причем ни в одну сторону, ни в другую.

Так что скорее здесь некий казус восприятия произошел. Мы сами так воспринимаем эту конструкцию "не должен" - как эквивалент или близкое к "должен не", почти что как идиому: в том смысле, что значение целого не вытекает прямо из значения составляющих. Грамматического объяснения тут нету.

*А вот примеры у Вас (да и у Людмилы тоже) не совсем удачные. Они не способствуют пониманию, только путают, не давая смотреть в корень проблемы. Надо именно такие информационные, как я попытался, где есть над чем подумать, а не просто принять к сведению. Но что-то больше ничего в голову не приходит*.

Comment: По-моему, должно быть "Я не должен обращать вниманиЕ (на что-то конкретное)", но "должен не обращать вниманиЯ ((как раз как у вас) на конкретное или ни на что, неважно)". В первом случае, по-моему, нельзя сказать "не должен обращать внимания *ни на что*" — если уже "не должен", то имеется в виду что-то определённое.

Comment: *По-моему, должно быть "Я не должен обращать вниманиЕ (на что-то конкретное)", но "должен не обращать вниманиЯ*  - Это все очень субъективно. В классическом понимании - да, именно так и рекомендовали (во времена Пушкина), но сейчас эти вольности давно закреплены, обсуждалось тут неоднократно. Но как бы то там ни было, это не сказывается на основной мысли.

Comment: Конечно, не сказывается.))

Answer (score 1):

"Не должен" встречается гораздо чаще, чем "должен не". Думаю, что "должен не" практически всегда можно заменить на "не должен". Обратное неверно.